# Stopping execution of plugin or deactivating running plugin using plugin name without closing QGIS in pyqgis?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

How do I stop the execution of plugin or deactivate the running plugin using plugin name without closing QGIS in pyqgis?

```
lstofplugins=qgis.utils.active_plugins
for k in range(len(lstofplugins)-2):
    self.iface.actionExit().trigger()
```

I have tried this coding ,but it is closing QGIS application itself..

Answer (score 2):

You could try unloading the plugin:

```
qgis.utils.unloadPlugin('GdalTools')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is automatically coded when I built my plugin with QGIS Plugin Builder:

```
def onClosePlugin(self):
    """Cleanup necessary items here when plugin dockwidget is closed"""
    # disconnects
    self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.disconnect(self.onClosePlugin)
    self.pluginIsActive = False
```